# Webrtc - Cannot read property 'addIceCandidate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc

I am getting the error from this page. The error is *client.js:166 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addIceCandidate' of undefined*. Below is the Code. How to remove that error? The video from the other browser is sending stream to the server, while adding the stream in both browser, there becomes the error. Where is the error occurs after it got stream.

```
var divSelectRoom = document.getElementById("selectRoom");  
var divConsultingRoom  = document.getElementById("consultingRoom");   
var inputRoomNumber = document.getElementById("roomNumber");   
var btnGoRoom = document.getElementById("goRoom");  
var localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");   
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");

// these are the global variables

var roomNumber;
var localStream;
var remotestream;
var rtcPeerConnection;

//these are the STUN servers

var iceServers = {
    'iceServers': [ 
        {
            url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        },
        {
            url:'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'
        },
        {
            url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
            credential: 'muazkh',
            username: 'webrtc@live.com'
        }
    ]
};

var streamConstraints = { audio: true, video: true };
        var isCaller;

    // Here we connect to the socket iO server. We Will create it later. 


var socket = io();
    // Here we Odd a click event to the button




btnGoRoom.onclick = function() {
        if (inputRoomNumber.value == ""){
            alert("Please type a room number");
        }
        else {
            roomNumber = inputRoomNumber.value; //we take the value from the element 
            socket.emit('create or join', roomNumber); //we send a message to server 
            divSelectRoom.style = "display: none;"; //hide selectRoom div 
            divConsultingRoom.style = "display block;"; //show consultingRoom div 
        }
    };

// when server emits created

socket.on("created", function(room){ 
console.log('created function');
    //caller gets user media devices with defined constraints
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then(function(stream){
        
        console.log('Created function');
        const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
        const video = document.getElementById('localVideo');
        video.srcObject = stream;
        localStream = stream; //sets local stream to variable
        //localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream); //shows stream to user
        isCaller = true;//sets current user as caller
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('An error occured when accessing media devices');
         console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    });
});

// when server emits ends
socket.on("joined", function(room){
    console.log('Joined function');
    //caller gets user media devices with defined constraints
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then(function(stream){
        localStream = stream; //sets local stream to variable
        const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
        const video = document.getElementById('localVideo');
        video.srcObject = stream;
        
        //localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream); //shows stream to user
        socket.emit('ready',roomNumber); //sends message to the server
        console.log('Joined function');
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('An error occured when accessing media devices');
         console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    });
});
        
//when server emits ready
socket.on('ready', function(){
    console.log('client ready function');
    if(isCaller){
        //creates an RTCPeerConnection object
        rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
        
        //adds event listeners to the newly created object
        rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
        rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = onAddStream;
        
        //add the current local stream to the object
        rtcPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
        
        //prepares an offer
        rtcPeerConnection.createOffer(setLocalAndOffer, function(e){
            console.log(e);
            });
    }
});

//when server emits offer
socket.on('offer',function(event){
    
    if(isCaller){
        console.log('client offer function');
        //creates an RTCPeerConnection object
        rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
        
        //adds event listeners to the newly created object
        rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
        rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = onAddStream;
        
        //adds the current local stream to the object
        rtcPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
        
        //stores the offer as remote description
        rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));
        
        //Prepares an Answer
        rtcPeerConnection.createAnswer(setLocalAndAnswer, function(e){
            console.log(e);
            });
    }
});

//when server emits answer
socket.on('answer', function(event){ 
    console.log('client answer function');
    //stores it as remote description
    rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));
});

//when server emits candidate
socket.on('candidate', function(event){ 
    console.log('client candidate function');
    
    var pc1 = {
      addIceCandidate : function(val) {
        console.log(val);
      }
    }
 
    
    //creates a candidate object
    var candidate1 = new RTCIceCandidate({
        type: 'offer',
        sdpMLineIndex: event.label,
        candidate: event.candidate
    });
    addIceCandidate(candidate1);
    
    // if(rtcPeerConnection)
        // console.log('Okay Peer'); 
            // //stores candidate
   // rtcPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate); 
});

function addIceCandidate(message) {
    if (message.candidate != null) { 
        rtcPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(message);
    }    
}

//when a user receives the other user's video and audio stream
function onAddStream(event){
    console.log('On Add Stream function');
    const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
    const rvideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
    rvideo.srcObject = event.stream;
    //remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    remoteStream = event.stream;
}

//These are the functions referenced before as listeners for the peer connection 
//sends a candidate message to server
function onIceCandidate(event){
    console.log('On Ice candidate function');
    if(event.candidate){
        console.log('sending ice candidate');
        socket.emit('candidate', {
            type: 'candidate',
            label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
            candidate: event.candidate.candidate,
            room: roomNumber
        });
    }
}

//stores offer and sends message to server
function setLocalAndOffer(sessionDescription){
    console.log('LocalAndOffer function');
    rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    socket.emit('offer', {
        type: 'offer',
        sdp: sessionDescription,
        room: roomNumber
    });
}

//stores answer and sends message to server
function setLocalAndAnswer(sessionDescription){
    console.log('LocalAndAnswer function');
    rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    socket.emit('answer', {
        type: 'answer',
        sdp: sessionDescription,
        room: roomNumber
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably sending the `candidate` socket message before the `rtcPeerConnection` is initialized. Then you get the error in the `addIceCandidate` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have a webrtc peer connection object before you call `addIceCandidate` when `candidate` web socket message arrives.

Once you init it and add event andlers it can any moment find ice candidates and hence trigger the related event, `onicecandidate`. Same for the session descriptions and its related event `onnegotiationneeded` event.

So be ready on other end you send those messages over websocket to upon they trigger on one end.

Comment: Okay I will check it

Comment: @Rajaram any progress?